# ionic2 provider "cannot load module"

Tags: typescript, ionic2, angular2-services, ionic2-providers

I'm trying to add a provider to my application,but getting this error

**Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "../providers/login/loginservice"**

Project structure

[image: this is my project structure]

Here is how the app.module.ts looks

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { HttpModule} from '@angular/http';


import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { Loginpage } from '../pages/loginpage/loginpage';

import { Loginservice } from '../providers/login/loginservice';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    Loginpage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    Loginpage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    Loginservice,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

loginpage.ts where i'm trying to use the provider

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Loginservice } from '../../providers/login/loginservice';

/**
 * Generated class for the Loginpage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-loginpage',
  templateUrl: 'loginpage.html'
  })
export class Loginpage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public loginservice : Loginservice) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad Loginpage');
  }
  login(){
    console.log("inside Login");
    //this.loginservice.doLogin();
  }

}
```

*Update:Adding the loginservice code.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
  Generated class for the Loginservice provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class Loginservice {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello Loginservice Provider');
  }

}
```

I'm not able to find any solution to this.
I tried changing the paths and removing and adding the provider again.
as of now the provider doesn't have any functionality as i'm j ust trying ti successfully import it.

Error Screenshot

[image]

Please guide me.

Thanks
Shruti Nair

Comment: loginservice.ts doesn't have any code at all..? Or do you have the export function in the file and still get this error..?

Comment: @raja:I have added the loginservice file as well.It has the export function

Comment: Have you tried restarting your ionic serve?

Comment: can you copy the error?

Comment: Move your `loginservice` to `pages` folder then import it with new path. Is it imported?

Comment: I tried restarting but nothing still the same error in terminal
 typescript: src/pages/loginpage/loginpage.ts, line: 18 
            Cannot find name 'Loginservice'. 

      L18:  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public loginservice : Loginservice) {

Comment: @ Fernando Del Olmo upated the question with the error

Comment: This error usually occurs when there is a problem with the imports. Check all the imports and If you have a github repo for this, kindly share the link.

Comment: @Duannx:i copied the file to pages folder and then tried importing it and it worked.
But is it the right way?and what would be the reason for this behaviour.Cant we keep it in seperate provider folder and then import it.

Comment: I tried keeping it in a separate provider folder, and it works fine..

Comment: @Raja:Can u help me find my mistake?.I think my imports and paths are correct so then whats the issue.

Comment: @ShrutiNair Ensure that you correctly use @IonicPage() annotation.

Comment: I think, you might not have saved the file, because the first error you posted was Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "../providers/login/loginservice; whereas the file was at '../../providers/login/loginservice;

Comment: @ShrutiNair: It is not the right way. Do it to check your provider file is fine. Seem like your error orccur only in `loginpage.ts file`, not in `app.module.ts` file right?

Comment: Please check the code at github
https://github.com/shruti1006/Ecart

This again is causing the same problem.
Let me know if u get a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code you provided in the link above

In the src/providers directory you have the loginservice.ts file but in loginpage.ts your import is

```
import { Loginservice } from '../../providers/login/loginservice';
```

There is no login directory, so the import should be

```
import { Loginservice } from '../../providers/loginservice';
```

Kindly change it in the app.module.ts file as well

```
import { Loginservice } from '../providers/loginservice';
```

Hope this helps you, Thanks.